# How to call Child function from Parent / Pass Props to a Parent component without using ref methods?

Tags: reactjs

I want to call a Child function `OpenTest()` from Parent component and display a variable "greeting".

So I tried to use Props like

```
<Child greeting={greeting}/>
```

and display it. It works when I want to send props from parent to Child

1. I want to call `OpenTest()` from Parent.js
2. I want to display "greeting" in Parent too

```
//Parent.js
import React from 'react'
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.greeting}
            <Child >
                <button onClick={props.Opentest}>Open Test</button>
            </Child>
        </div>
    );
}

//Child.js
import React from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  const greeting = "Hello";

  function openTest() {
    console.log("Done");
  }

  return  ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but one thing you need to understand is that props can only go from parent to child. If you want to update the parent from the child, you should consider using a class component which has a state property, that can be updated through a callback. An alternative approach is to use the use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Here is an example of how you might be able to accomplish this:

```
//Parent.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      greeting: ""
    };

    this.updateGreeting = this.updateGreeting.bind(this);
  }

  updateGreeting(greeting) {
    this.setState({ greeting });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.greeting}
        <Child updateGreeting={this.updateGreeting} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Child.js
import React from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  const greeting = "Hello";

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => props.updateGreeting(greeting)}>
        click to update greeting to hello
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```